# How do you Derive $\Delta x = -\textbf{H}^{-1}\textbf{g}$ from Quasi-Newtonian Methods?

Tags: matrices, optimization, vectors, maxima-minima, quadrics

The equation:

$$\Delta x =  -\mathbf{H}^{-1}\mathbf{g}$$

Is the key part of Quasi-Newtonian methods, where $\Delta x$ is the coordinate shift required to reach a minimum, $\textbf{H}$ is the hessian of some function $f(\mathbf{\vec{x}})$, and $\textbf{g}$ is its gradient.

Given some initial point $\mathbf{\vec{x}}_0$, along with $\textbf{H}$ and $\textbf{g}$, the equation gives you $\Delta x$ which is the coordinate change to $\mathbf{\vec{x}}$ that is required to put $f(\mathbf{\vec{x}})$ at some local extrema. Close to a minimum it will find a minimum point.

However, in the four references I have read on this matter [1-4], I have found no good explanation of why $\Delta x = -\mathbf{H}^{-1}\mathbf{g}$. Even in the paper which establishes this equation[5], I find the derivation quite hard to follow.

How can one derive this equation? Are there any resources which go over its derivation in more detail?

**References:**

[1] *Press, William H.; Teukolsky, Saul A.; Vetterling, William T.; Flannery, Brian P.*, Numerical recipes. The art of scientific computing., Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-88068-8/hbk; 978-0-511-33239-5/ebook). xxi, 1235 p. (2007). [ZBL1132.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1132.65001).

[2] *Gale, Julian D.; Rohl, Andrew L.*, [**The general utility lattice program (GULP)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/0892702031000104887), Mol. Simul. 29, No. 5, 291-341 (2003). [ZBL1047.81583](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1047.81583).

[3] *Fletcher, R.; Powell, M. J. D.*, [**A rapidly convergent descent method for minimization**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/6.2.163), Comput. J. 6, 163-168 (1963). [ZBL0132.11603](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0132.11603).

[4] *Shanno, D. F.*, [**Conditioning of quasi-Newton methods for function minimization**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2004840), Math. Comput. 24(1970), 647-656 (1971). [ZBL0225.65073](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0225.65073).

[5] *Davidon, William C.*, [**Variable metric method for minimization**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0801001), SIAM J. Optim. 1, No. 1, 1-17 (1991). [ZBL0752.90062](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0752.90062).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off of Ian's answer, it seems the equation is derived thus. You have some function $f(\mathbf{\vec{x}})$, whose gradient is given $\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}})$. Extreme points can be found at $\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}) = 0$, and so we would like to approximate this function with a Taylor series:

$$\begin{split}
\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}} + \Delta {\vec{x}}) & \approx \nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}})((\mathbf{\vec{x}} + \Delta {\vec{x}}) - \mathbf{\vec{x}})^0 + \nabla (\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}))((\mathbf{\vec{x}} + \Delta {\vec{x}}) - \mathbf{\vec{x}})^1 \\[0.5em]
& = \nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}) + \nabla (\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}))\Delta {\vec{x}}\end{split}$$

Where you are evaluating the function at $\mathbf{\vec{x}}$, and the input to the function is now: $\mathbf{\vec{x}} + \Delta {\vec{x}}$.

As we would like the gradient to evaluate to zero with the step $\Delta {\vec{x}}$ we set the LHS to zero and rearrange to get the following:

$$\begin{split}
0 & = \nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}) + \nabla (\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}))\Delta {\vec{x}} \\[0.5em]
-\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}) & = \nabla (\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}})) \Delta {\vec{x}} \\[0.5em]
-\frac{\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}})}{\nabla (\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}))} & = \Delta {\vec{x}}\end{split}$$

And because $f(\mathbf{\vec{x}})$ is a function of many variables, its gradient of its gradient is the Hessian written $\mathbf{H}$, and so:

$$\begin{split}
\frac{1}{\nabla (\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}))} & = \mathbf{H}^{-1} \\[0.5em]
\nabla f(\mathbf{\vec{x}}) & = \mathbf{g}
\end{split}$$

Where $\mathbf{g}$ is the gradient. Putting it all together we get:

$$ \Delta \vec{x} = -\mathbf{H}^{-1} \mathbf{g}$$

Comment: You have some sloppy notation, for example $\nabla f'$ is quite weird (in math we sometimes write $\nabla(\nabla f)$ or $\nabla^2 f$ but unfortunately $\nabla^2$ is also common notation for the Laplacian) and dividing a number by a matrix isn't really right. But other than notation this is right.

Comment: Okay thanks! I was wondering about that, because whilst $\nabla^2$ seems like the right notation, I also found it was used for the Laplacian. So is the common work around in that situation to write it as you have above: $\nabla (\nabla f)$?

Comment: I've also seen $D^2$ in some contexts, or $H$ for Hessian (though that has a problem with inability to generalize to the $n$th order Taylor expansion).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve $\nabla f(x)=0$. You perform Taylor expansion near the current point $x$ and try to set the new gradient equal to $\nabla f(x^*)=0$. So you want $0=\nabla f(x) + H(x) \Delta x$, using Taylor's theorem. Rearranging you get $\Delta x = -H(x)^{-1} (\nabla f(x))$.

What's more confusing is why the Newton search *direction* is useful with a step size that isn't $1$.

Comment: It seems like you're saying take the Taylor expansion of the gradient function, is that what you're saying? I wonder if you could expand on your answer to make it more explicit? Apologies if it seems obvious.

Comment: @Connor You can view it as either Taylor expanding the gradient and finding the zero or Taylor expanding the objective function and finding the minimum of the resulting quadratic function. I wrote this from the point of view of the former.

Comment: @Connor Sure. ${}{}$

Comment: Could What does $x^*$ mean? I think it means $x_0 - \Delta x$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Connor $x^*$ is the point you are trying to find.

Comment: How are you getting a $\Delta x$ to fall out of the equation then? Is it possible you could give the form of the Taylor expansion?

Comment: @Connor More carefully, you would like to have $\nabla f(x_{k+1})=0$, you estimate $\nabla f(x_{k+1}) \approx \nabla f(x_k)+H(x_k)(x_{k+1}-x_k)$, then approximate the LHS by just $0$ and solve for $x_{k+1}$ on the RHS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130735/discussion-between-connor-and-ian).